# ¿cómo hago que me aparezca el login de spring security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, login, spring-security

estaba haciendo un curso de spring security, pero cuando login o cuando quiero ir al path de login me da un error y no me mustra el login que esta por defecto en spring (todo esto lo probe en el navegador)

Entonces lo probe en postman y cuando le doy al path /login me da error 401 (sin pasarle bassic auth )
Si le paso el auth ahi me da error 404 (supongo que es pq no tengo un controller para eso (pero yo quuiero usar el login de spring)

**esto tengo en mi config**

```
package com.api.security.infra.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/index2").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(login ->{
                    login.loginPage("/login")
                    .successHandler(successHandler()) //donde se redirige luego del login
                    .permitAll();
                })
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->{
                    sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .expiredUrl("/login");
                    sessionManagement.sessionFixation().migrateSession();
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }


    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler(){
        return ((req, res, auth) -> {
            res.sendRedirect("/api/v1/index");
        });
    }
}
```

si comento la configuración del fromLogin() ahí si me pide usuario pero ya no me redirije a la url /api/v1/index

**este es mi controller:**

```
package com.api.security.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class CustomerController {
    
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index(){
        return "Hola mundo";
    }


    @GetMapping("/index2")
    public String index2(){
        return "Hola mundo sin sguridad";
    }
}
```

[comparto mi repositorio también por si alguien quiere ver mas :](https://github.com/KevinStockmanns/spring-security)

Answer (score 0):

asi me funciono, igual hago el mismo curso y tu codigo me ayudo a resolver un problema aunque yo aun no llego a la parte del successhandler

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/v1/index2").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(login ->{
                    login.isCustomLoginPage();
                    //.successHandler(successHandler()) //donde se redirige luego del login
                   // .permitAll();
                }).build();
    }

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/v1/index2").permitAll();
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .formLogin(login ->{
                login.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(successHandler());
                //.successHandler(successHandler()) //donde se redirige luego del login
               // .permitAll();
            }).build();
}
```